# Range in DCT coefficents MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, quantization, dct

I am trying to find the range over which the coefficients of an 8 x 8 block varies for various block of an image. Do I need to generate a histogram for the values of is there a function in matlab?

Comment: I'm not sure, but won't the `min` and `max` functions work on arrays/array blocks in MATLAB, too?

Comment: May be the following link of interest
http://lists.mpegif.org/pipermail/mp4-tech/2010-November/009486.html

Answer (score 0):

For pixel values between [0, 255], 8x8 block DCT values can take values between -65280.0 and 65280.0 (±255x8x8). Some image and video codecs represent 8x8 block dct values in signed 16 bit integers in [−32768, 32767]. See JPEG article of Wikipedia for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For pixel values between 0 and 255, the coefficients of for a 8x8 block 2d DCT can take the value ±16320